# Geting distinct items in a table column in Django

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Part (models.Model):
adder=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="added_models", verbose_name=_('adder'), editable=False)
```

I'm trying to select all the distinct `adder`s of a `Part` object. To do this I tried:

`Part.objects.filter('adder', flat=True).distinct()`

But it is not giving me distinct values and repeats the `adder` values.

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On a side note, `adder` is kind of a confusing name.  I usually use `created_by` or `added_by` for these types of fields.  Think of it in plain in english: "The Part was added by John Smith" is way clearer then "John Smith was the adder of the Part".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

User.objects.filter(id__in = Part.objects.values_list('adder', flat=True))

Comment: Oh ... interesting. Is this because it's a foreignkey relation? Would the way I wrote it work if it was a non-foreignkey relation? (ie. just a regular field)? Just curious...

Comment: Well, its really straight forward Foreign Key is a Many To one relationship if it would had been a many to many relationship what you are trying to do would have had been possible! If you just try to get all the adder by using this Part.adder.all() its going to raise an error as is not the case in many-to-many relationship.